# HashMap<String, Boolean> getValue returns Boolean but java tries to cast to String

Tags: java, android

```
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Boolean>> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Sound s: drumThumper.soundsToe) {
        HashMap l = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
        l.put("name", s.getSound().replace(".wav", ""));
        l.put("checkbox", s==drumThumper.selectedSoundToe);
        list.add(l);
    }

    SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(activity.getApplicationContext(), list, R.layout.checkbox_list, new String[]{"name", "checkbox"}, new int[]{R.id.name, R.id.checkbox});
    listPopupWindow.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);

    listPopupWindow.setOnItemClickListener((parent, view1, position, id) -> {
        HashMap<String, Boolean> item = list.get(position);
        Map.Entry<String,Boolean> entry = item.entrySet().iterator().next();
        Boolean oldValue = entry.getValue();
        entry.setValue(!oldValue);
    });
```

but I'm getting `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean at lambda$onToeLongClick$1(Dialogues.java:165)` on

`Boolean oldValue = entry.getValue();`

How can that be possible? The HashMap is obviously from `String` to `Boolean`. And I'm calling `.getValue` which even the intellisense says returns a `Boolean`

Comment: Start here: `HashMap l ` ... that is a raw type. Dont use that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting a warning about using a raw type where you have `HashMap` listed, and the warning is there for *exactly* this reason. When you say

```
l.put("name", s.getSound().replace(".wav", ""));
```

you are putting a `String` value into the map even though you promised only to put `Boolean`s in it.

I can't advise on how exactly to best rework this code, since it's not entirely clear what your intention is, but I will note that it's usually easier to use a `Set<K>` instead of a `Map<K, Boolean>`.

Answer (score 2):

your problem is here:

```
l.put("name", s.getSound().replace(".wav", ""));
```

you put inside HashMap 2 strings. And when you try to get boolean value, he find a string.

Comment: If you accept this answer, please close the question.